# Warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, ponteiro, warnings

Dei uma pesquisada mas não entendi muito bem o que significa isso e o que isso fala sobre meu código.
Eu tenho essa função `cria_palavra` que retorna um ponteiro, aí no `main`, quando eu vou receber esse retorno em outra função `insere_final` dá esse *warning* do titulo

```
int insere_lista_final(int i, Lista* li, char *dt) // parametros da func

insere_lista_final(i,li,cria_palavra(i,aux,li));


char cria_palavra(int i, char *aux, Lista *li){

char *plv;
plv = (char*)malloc(i*sizeof(char));// aloca a palavra
strncpy(plv,aux,i);// passa aux para plv
plv[i]='\0'; // retira o lixo

return *plv;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos começar por primeiro perceber os problemas que tem, e que estão todos relacionados com a concordância nos tipos.

- A sua função `cria_palavra` devolve um `char`:

  ```
  char cria_palavra(int i, char *aux, Lista *li){
  //^--
  ```

  Mas a função `insere_lista_final` espera um `char*`:

  ```
  int insere_lista_final(int i, Lista* li, char *dt)
  //                                            ^--
  ```

  Por isso está a passar um `char` num sitio que espera um `char*`:

  ```
  insere_lista_final(i,li, cria_palavra(i,aux,li));
  //                          ^--- isto devolve char mas espera-se char* no 3 parâmetro
  ```

  Quando não for evidente, comece por separar as instruções e não encadear todas umas nas outras. Separar torna mais claro pois obriga-lhe a ver o resultado de cada coisa:

  ```
  char palavra = cria_palavra(i,aux,li); //aqui torna-se mais claro que sai um char da função
  insere_lista_final(i, li, palavra);
  ```

  Aqui torna-se mais claro o problema, pois eu separei as instruções.

  Repare que isto é diferente do que você entendeu do código quando diz:

  > Eu tenho essa função `cria_palavra` que retorna um ponteiro
- A função `cria_palavra` não devolve uma palavra mas sim a sua primeira letra. Dentro da função alocou espaço para a palavra toda e copiou o texto recebido com `strcpy` mas depois devolve um `char` que é apenas uma letra com `return *plv;`. O próprio tipo da função está marcado como `char`(letra) em vez de `char*` (ponteiro para char).

  Este segundo problema afeta o primeiro problema dos tipos não jogarem.

Para corrigir os dois problemas deve começar por primeiro alterar a função que cria uma palavra para devolver o tipo correto:

```
char* cria_palavra(int i, char *aux, Lista *li) {
//  ^-- agora devolver char* e não char
    char *plv;
    plv = (char*)malloc(i*sizeof(char));
    strncpy(plv,aux,i);
    plv[i]='\0';

    return plv; // sem *
}
```

Depois a chamada é igual ao que estava que já não irá dar erro, pois já passa `char*` no terceiro parâmetro como esperado:

```
insere_lista_final(i, li, cria_palavra(i, aux, li));
```